# Can't config constructor with one parameter

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

I try to config RedisManagerPool.
RedisManagerPool has 3 constructor, but I can't setup constructor with one string parameter(host).
It is invoke **Must provide at least** exception.

Is it code works, in comment broken code.

```
var host = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Data.Redis.ConnectionString");
var list = new List<string>() {host};
//TODO: Can't setup constructor with host parameter. I don't the reason.
//For<IRedisClientsManager>()
//    .Add<RedisManagerPool>()
//    .Ctor<string>("host").Is(host);
For<IRedisClientsManager>()
.Add<RedisManagerPool>()
.Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("hosts").Is(list);
```

Comment: Try `.Is((IEnumerable<string>)list)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use *Use* instead of *Add*

```
For<IRedisClientsManager>()
.Use<RedisManagerPool>()
.Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("hosts").Is(list);
```